# How can I find which record in a table has most fields populated?

Tags: mysql

Or perhaps put another way: How can I find which record in a table has the least null or blank fields?

Without having to count every single field individually that is - the table has 161 fields.

Comment: There is no way without checking each and every field to know which row has most nulls, it doesnt make any logic to be able to do so without checking

Comment: You should consider redesign your schema.161 fields? columns? what?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by constructing a dynamic query like:

```
SELECT id,
       (IF(col1 = NULL OR col1 = "", 1, 0) +
        IF(col2 = NULL OR col3 = "", 1, 0) +
        ...
        IF(coln = NULL OR coln = "", 1, 0)
       ) AS null_count
FROM table_name
ORDER BY null_count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

This can be easily done by forming a new dynamic query using `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and then executing `dynamic sql query`. Also you might need to increase the maximum length of output from `GROUP_CONCAT` function by setting session level variable `group_concat_max_len` to higher value.

```
SET GLOBAL group_concat_max_len = 4294967295;

SELECT @query1 := CONCAT('SELECT id,
                                 (',
                         GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('IF(',COLUMN_NAME,' IS NULL OR ',
                                                   COLUMN_NAME,' = "", 1, 0
                                                ) 
                                           ') 
                                      SEPARATOR ' + '),
                                ') AS null_count
                         FROM table_name
                         ORDER BY null_count DESC
                         LIMIT 1')
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
      AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name';

PREPARE stmt FROM @query1; EXECUTE stmt; DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

## Example: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef9ab/7)

Comment: Thanks - but I'm not sure I understand. Your statement above appears to give me a query that returns a count of null or blank values for each column. This tells me which column has the most null or blank values. But what I wanted was which row has the most null or blank values.

Comment: No, this does not work! First of all @query1 will be NULL (yes, tested). Second, even when corrected your `PREPARE stmt...` will only call the last value of @query1 and therefore only return the value for the last column.

Comment: Tested and it does work on my machine..You must have forgotten to replace `table_name` with `your_table_name` which exists in your database.

Comment: See working SQLFiddle demo. There is no reason for `@query1` to be `NULL` as all the columns used in `CONCAT` are `NOT NULL`. Also `GROUP_CONCAT` function returns only one row so last row is same as first row.

Comment: Well, your sqlfiddle example doesn't even answer the question. The question is "which column has the most rows being null?". Your query answers with "row with id 3".

Comment: No OP says in comment above: `what I wanted was which row has the most null or blank values.`

Answer (score 1):

*DISCLAIMER: I got the question wrong, thought the OP was looking for the column of a table with the most NULLs. Nonetheless, maybe it's useful for anyone.*

Create a procedure like this:

```
drop procedure if exists test_most_pop_field;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE test_most_pop_field(IN tableName varchar(100))
BEGIN

DECLARE done INT DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE sql_query VARCHAR(255);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR 
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO tmp_result(columnName, numberOfEmptyRows) SELECT "', COLUMN_NAME, '" AS columnName, SUM(IF(',COLUMN_NAME,' IS NULL OR ', COLUMN_NAME,' = "", 1, 0)) AS numberEmptyRows FROM ', TABLE_NAME)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = SCHEMA()
AND TABLE_NAME = tableName;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '02000' SET done = 1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tmp_result;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_result(columnName varchar(100), numberOfEmptyRows int);

OPEN cur;

REPEAT
  FETCH cur INTO sql_query;
  IF NOT done THEN
    BEGIN
      SET @sql = sql_query; /*this extra step is necessary, cause otherwise it's a syntax error, don't ask me why*/
      PREPARE stmt FROM @sql; 
      EXECUTE stmt; 
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END;
  END IF;
UNTIL done END REPEAT;

CLOSE cur;

SELECT * FROM tmp_result ORDER BY numberOfEmptyRows DESC /*optionally LIMIT 1*/;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call it with the table name you want to examine:

```
CALL test_most_pop_field('yourTableName');
```